# Playing a midi file asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, midi

Is there a way to play a MIDI file note by note? Like for example when a key is pressed it only plays the first note of the midi file.

Ive tried it midi.js but i can only play, pause and resume the file.

Comment: Yes there is a way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently working on a midi event listener and therefore made a simple midi parser. You can download the project [here](https://github.com/Otto-AA/MidiPlayer) and then copy the MidiParser.js file from /build to your project.

You can use it like that (full example [here](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/Otto-AA/MidiPlayer/blob/master/examples/midiParser.html)):

```
// Create midi parser
var parser = new MidiParser();

// Load file and parse midi
var fileReader = new FileReader();
var midiFileInput = document.getElementById('midiFileInput');
midiFileInput.addEventListener('change', function(inputEvent) {
    if (!inputEvent.target.files.length)
        return false;

    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(inputEvent.target.files[0]);
    fileReader.onload = function(file) {
        var uint8Midi = new Uint8Array(file.target.result);
        var parsedMidi = parser.parseUint8(uint8Midi);
        // Use parsed midi
        document.body.innerHTML += '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(parsedMidi, null, 2) + '</pre>';
    };
});
```

The output of it will be an array of formatted noteOn and noteOff events.

Regarding your example, everytime the key is pressed you could use `var event = parsedMidi.shift()` to get the next event, or accessing it with an ascending index (`var event = parsedMidi[yourIndex]`).

If you want to play sounds you can use midi.js or [sample-player](https://github.com/danigb/sample-player). (haven't tested this one yet)

**Edit:**

Tutorial: https://github.com/Otto-AA/MidiPlayer/blob/master/tutorials/MidiParser.md

Documentation: https://github.com/Otto-AA/MidiPlayer/blob/master/docs/MidiParser.md

Comment: Thanks! It was really helpful. I´m having a little trouble playing the parsed midi. How exactly can i pass the event to the midi js player. I´m trying to advance through the whole midi note by note when any key input is detected.
Thanks for the further help, mate.

Comment: Something like `MIDI.noteOn(channel, note, velocity, delay)`
See https://github.com/mudcube/MIDI.js#midipluginjs---controls-midi-output
or https://github.com/mudcube/MIDI.js/blob/master/examples/Basic.html

Comment: Sir! The const parsedMidi is created inside the anonymous function, how can I access it in the global scope. So i can work with it. I tried returning parsedMidi but didnt worked.

Comment: You can create a global `var parsedMidi;`. Then, when you loaded the midi you can do `parsedMidi = parser.parseUint8(uint8Midi)`. Yet your other code will only be able to use parsedMidi after the asynchrounous load. You probably want to add some kind of onMidiLoad function where you put your code into that uses parsedMidi and call it when it loaded. As a site note, global variables are in most cases said to be bad :)

Comment: I managed to make it work. Thanks!. But I am having some issues when playing chords. I noticed that your parser plays a note off when a chord is supposed to play? Is there a way to parse and play chords?

Comment: You can create a detailed issue at the github page. I will look at it as soon as as possible, but probably not in the next few days :/